# Unable to hide triangulation lines in GeoGraphics

Tags: plotting, geographics

The following code produces a night region that shows triangulation. I thought that `EdgeForm[None]` would hide it, but it does not.

```
date = {2020, 01, 01, 8, 5};
tris = DiscretizeRegion[GeoGraphics`GeoEvaluate[DayHemisphere[date]], MaxCellMeasure -> 10];
p = MeshPrimitives[tris, 2][[All, 1]];
gp = Apply[{Mod[#1, 180, -90], Mod[#2, 360, -180]} &, Reverse[p, {3}], {2}];

g = Show[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 1200}],
   GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{Opacity[0.2]}], EdgeForm[None], 
Polygon[GeoPosition[gp]], DayNightTerminator[date]}, 
 GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", 
 "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{15, 50}]}, GeoCenter -> {15, 50}, 
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[20, "AngularDegrees"], 
 GeoGridLinesStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], AbsoluteThickness[2]}, 
 GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> LightGray, 
 "Ocean" -> White, 
 "Border" -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[1]]}]
 ]
```

12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)

Comment: Add `Method -> {"TransparentPolygonMesh" -> True}` to your call to `Show`.  Very nice graphic, by the way.